# Unable to malloc and free memory properly in my strtok program

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

So that's part of my program parsing one line of file into array num_args, which I use for further implementation:

```
while(fgets(str, 1024, f) > 0) {
    int id;
    int final_arg_num;
    int my_index;
    char *num_args[100];
    for (id = 0, line = strtok(str, " "); id < 100; id++) {
        if (line == NULL) {
            break;
        }   
        num_args[id] = malloc(16*sizeof(char));
        sscanf(line, "%s", num_args[id]);
        line = strtok(NULL, " "); 
    }   
    final_arg_num = id;

    char *storage_people = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*need);
    if (strcmp(num_args[0],"Movie:") != 0) {
        strcpy(storage_people,num_args[0]);
    } else {
        strcpy(storage_people,"");
    }
    for (my_index = 1; my_index < final_arg_num; my_index++) {
        if (strcmp(num_args[0],"Movie:") || (!strcmp(num_args[0],"Movie:") && my_index > 1))
            strcat(storage_people, " " );
        strcat(storage_people, num_args[my_index]);
    }

    if (strcmp(num_args[0],"Movie:") == 0) {
        // do something       
    } else {
        // do something
    }
    /**for (j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        if (num_args[j] != NULL) {
            free(num_args[j]);
        }
    }**/
    free(storage_people);
}
fclose(f);
```

If I don't free num_args, I get memory leak; If I uncomment the `free(num_args[j])` part of my program, I get valgrind error like this:

```
==3062== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3062==    at 0x401D3B: main (original.c:410)
==3062== 
==3062== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3062==    at 0x4C2BDA2: free (in .*)
==3062==    by 0x401D54: main (original.c:411)
==3062== 
==3062== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==3062==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in .*)
==3062==    by 0x401D54: main (original.c:411)
==3062==  Address 0x8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that

```
char *num_args[100];
```

declares an array of pointer, but they are uninitialized. Your `for` loop that
parses the line does not necessarily set all 100 spaces in the array, so some
are going to be left uninitialized and most probably `!= NULL`.

That's why `free` fails because at some point in your free-loop you are trying
to do `free(num_args[j])` for a `num_args[j]` that has not been initialized and
is not `NULL`, hence it crashes.

You have to initialized the array, either with `memset` like this

```
char *num_args[100];
memset(num_args, 0, sizeof num_args);
```

or by using an initialization list

```
char *num_args[100] = { NULL };
```

which initializes all pointer to a *null* pointer<sup>1,2</sup>.

And you should do the `fgets` check like this

```
while(fgets (str , 1024 , f))
```

or like this

```
while(fgets (str , 1024 , f) != NULL)
```

---

**Fotenotes**

<sup>1</sup>As [chux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49713859/unable-to-malloc-and-free-memory-properly-in-my-strtok-program/49714060#comment86441393_49714060) points out in the comments, my statement *which initializes all pointer to `NULL`.* is
not entirely true, as only the first element is initialized to `NULL`, all other
elements are initialized with a 0-bit pattern. There might be architectures
where `NULL` is not represented by a 0-bit pattern and the rest of the element
will not point to `NULL`. But in most architectures, `NULL` is 0-bit pattern and
the effect will be that all elements point to `NULL`. See
https://ideone.com/RYAyHm as an example of this compiled with GCC.

<sup>2</sup>I'm using the phrasing used by [chux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49713859/unable-to-malloc-and-free-memory-properly-in-my-strtok-program/49714060#comment86442527_49714060) second comment on that, the explanation is very good.

Comment: "which initialized all pointer to `NULL`." -> not quite: `char *num_args[100] = { NULL };` will initialize the first element to `NULL`, the remaining 99 to a zero-bit pattern. IAC, all will be _null pointers_.  On expectational platforms, `NULL` is not a zero bit pattern.

Comment: @chux yes your right, I've added a footnote about that. But are there really architectures out there that people are using where `NULL` is not a 0-bit pattern?

Comment: @chux or is that so, C11 says that the pointers are initialized to NULL (6.7.9 p10 and p20)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala C11 does not say says that the pointers are initialized to `NULL` . "if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;". That  effect is _functional_ similar in that the pointer is a _null pointer_, even if it is not `NULL`. Recall a system may have more than one _null pointer_ encoding. p21 applies here: again the result is a _null pointer_, even if not the same same a `NULL`, it will have the same functionality, although potential different representation. Had this answer said "which initializes all pointer to a _null pointer_", there would be less reason to comment.

Comment: @chux thanks for the feedback, I've changed the wording for yours (and obviously added a remark that you've said these words).

Comment: @Pablo My [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49713859/unable-to-malloc-and-free-memory-properly-in-my-strtok-program/49714060?noredirect=1#comment86441393_49714060) was a subtle point to your fine answer. The major concern really is that `some_type_args[100] = { some_zero_like_value };` initializes the first element as `some_zero_like_value` and the rest with default initialization - which are "zero-like", yet may differ is a subtle way.  Keep up your good answers.

Comment: @chux: This is a byzantine discussion, but `char *num_args[100] = { NULL };` is much less problematic than `memset(num_args, 0, sizeof num_args);`, which initializes the array to all bits zero which is not necessarily a null pointer representation. Whether null pointers may have multiple representations does not really matter: shouldn't all null pointer representations compare equal?

Comment: standard also guaranty that `char *num_args[100] = {0};` will corectly assign all values of `num_args` to `NULL`, but `memset(num_args, 0, sizeof num_args);` will not. By the way, I don't like this solution, it's would be much better to count the number of valid value in the array instead of just all initialize to `NULL`, we are in C not JAVA. "my statement which initializes all pointer to NULL. is not entirely true, as only the first element is initialized to NULL, all other elements are initialized with a 0-bit pattern.", this is wrong @chux

Comment: @Stargateur I agree "all other elements are initialized with a 0-bit pattern" is better as "if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;".  I disagree that standard specifies "`char *num_args[100] = {0};` will assign all values of `num_args` to `NULL`.  It will assign the last 99 elements to some _null pointer_, be it `(void*) NULL` or some other _null pointer_.  Functionally that is scant difference.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the main loop uses a bogus test for end of file: you should instead write `while (fgets(str, 1024, f) != NULL) {`
- The loop to free the allocated pointer should stop at `id`: beyond this index, all pointers are uninitialized, hence passing them to `free` has undefined behavior. Note also that it is perfectly safe to pass a null pointer to `free`. There is no need to initialize this array if you modify the loop this way:

  ```
  for (j = 0; j < id; j++) {
      free(num_args[j]);
  }
  ```
- the way you store the words into the array is both inefficient and risky: you allocate 16 bytes of memory and use `sscanf()` with a `%s` conversion specifier to copy the *word* parsed by `strtok`.

  - You should pass the maximum number of characters to store into `num_args[id]` with `sscanf(line, "%15s", num_args[id]);`.
  - Note that unless there are other white space characters in the source string, such as `\r`, `\n`, `\t`... you can just store the word with `num_args[id] = strdup(line);`.
  - If these characters should be considered separators in the source string, pass them to `strtok`: `line = strtok(str, " \t\r\n\v\f")`
- The copy and concatenation of words into `storage_people` is also problematic: you do not test if `need` bytes are enough space for the resulting string, including the terminating null byte. You should use a utility function to concatenate 2 strings with reallocation to the proper size.